# How to pass data from one fragment to another through RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

I need to pass user id from Firebase from one fragment to another when clicking on RecyclerView item. I tried to do it via Bundle, but I get the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.os.Bundle.get(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Sending Fragment:

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
    new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, FindFriendsViewHolder>(options) {
  @Override
  protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FindFriendsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull User model) {
    holder.setUserName(model.getName());
    Picasso.get().load(model.getImageURL()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_baseline_person_24).into(holder.userImage);

    holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String userid = getRef(holder.getBindingAdapterPosition()).getKey().toString();
            Fragment fragment= new AnotherUserFragment();

            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("userid", userid);

            AddUserFragment addUserFragment = new AddUserFragment();
            addUserFragment.setArguments(args);

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.main_body, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();

        }
    });
  }
```

Receiving Fragment:

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
String receiverUserId = args.get("userid").toString();
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "your id: " + receiverUserId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting arguments to a different fragment rather than navigating fragment

```
String userid = getRef(holder.getBindingAdapterPosition()).getKey().toString();
//you are navigating to this fragment, so set arguments to this
Fragment fragment = new AnotherUserFragment();

Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("userid", userid);

AddUserFragment addUserFragment = new AddUserFragment();
addUserFragment.setArguments(args);

//add this line to set arguments for the actual target fragment
fragment.setArguments(args);

FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.main_body, fragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```